# UITableViewAutomaticDimension not working on Xcode 11 and iOS 13 with trait variations

Tags: uitableview, autolayout, traits, ios13, xcode11

I have view in xib that registered to tableView and calculate height through UITableViewAutomaticDimension. And all worked fine before update to Xcode 11 and iOS 13, now height small and incorrect.

What I noticed, if I remove all constraints trait variations it appears to work again. But if I add at least one trait variation for constraints(no matter horizontal or vertical) As on this image
[image: As on this image]

Even with two checks, it breaks. But such variation working good, not breaks layout

[image: But such variation working good, not breaks layout].

Maybe bug in Xcode or something. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: You'll need to edit your question with more detail. I just did a quick test with Xcode 11 / iOS 13, using a XIB for tableViewCell, and trait variations on two labels (font size / style / color), and auto-layout row height works fine.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. XCode is adding a 44 height constraint automatically to the cell, from nowhere, and it breaks evertyhing.

Comment: yes i am also facing any solution ??